# Chaining VPNs by docker

Tags: vpn, openvpn, docker

I want to use  [Lokinet](https://oxen.io/) over a primary vpn. The way I know (I'm noob) is using two docker containers one for primary VPN and one for Lokinet. So I created a docker for primary VPN called openvpn (it uses an openVPN connection) and tried:

`# docker run --net=container:openvpn --name lokinet --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device=/dev/net/tun massiveboxe/lokinet:latest`

The problem is when I run: `# ./lokinet-vpn --up --exit exit.loki` inside lokinet docker, the external IP of it doesn’t change. It happen only when I use `--net=container:openvpn`